# AngularJS can't find my controller

Tags: angularjs

I know this is a common problem but I haven't been able to find a solution by reading through previously asked questions.

I'm actually getting two errors but the first one is about angular not being able to find my controller.

http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.2/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp.controllers

My directory structure looks like the following:

```
.
└── static
    ├── index.html
    ├── js
    │   ├── app.js
    │   └── controllers.js
    ├── lib
    │   └── angular-ui-router.min.js
    └── partials
        ├── view1.html
        └── view2.html
```

My index file looks like the following:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Hello AngularJS</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ui-view></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.2/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My app.js file looks like the following:

```
(function(angular) {

    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'myApp.controllers']);

    app.config(function($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state('view1', {
            url: '/view1',
            templateUrl: 'partials/view1.html',
            controller: 'View1Controller'
        }).state('view2', {
            url: '/view2',
            templateUrl: 'partials/view2.html',
            controller: 'View2Controller'
        });
    }).run(function($state) {
        $state.go('view2');
    });

})(angular);
```

My controller.js file looks like the following:

```
(function(angular) {
    var app = angular.module('myApp.controllers');

    app.controller('View1Controller', function($scope) {
        $scope.data = 'my view 1';
    });

    app.controller('View2Controller', function($scope) {
        $scope.data = 'my view 2';
    });

})(angular);
```

Also a second [error](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.2/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.2%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DmyApp.controllers%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.4.2%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253DmyApp.controllers%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Error%2520(native)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.4.2%252Fangular.min.js%253A6%253A416%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.4.2%252Fangular.min.js%253A24%253A66%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520a%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.4.2%252Fangular.min.js%253A23%253A109)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520P.bootstrap%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.4.2%252Fangular.min.js%253A23%253A352)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.4.2%252Fangular.min.js%253A37%253A451%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520m%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.4.2%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A322)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.4.2%252Fangular.min.js%253A37%253A229)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.4.2%252Fangular.min.js%253A37%253A398%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520m%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.4.2%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A322)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.2%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A416%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.2%2Fangular.min.js%3A38%3A154%0A%20%20%20%20at%20m%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.2%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A322)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.2%2Fangular.min.js%3A37%3A229)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.2%2Fangular.min.js%3A37%3A398%0A%20%20%20%20at%20m%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.2%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A322)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.2%2Fangular.min.js%3A37%3A229)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20eb%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.2%2Fangular.min.js%3A40%3A503)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.2%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A339) which might be related.

As stated above angular is unable to find my controller. Does anyone have a clue about what I'm doing wrong? Please let me know if I need to paste more code.

I've shared the code on github in case someone finds it easier to deal with.

https://github.com/tonsV2/angular-ui.route/tree/master/src/main/resources/static

Comment: Try to change order position of loaded scripts. The file `app.js` should be loaded earlier than `controllers.js`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In angular `angular.module()` is a setter and a getter. According to the [`angular.module`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module) docs (via [@DanAtkinson's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32805464/angularjs-cant-find-my-controller/32805483?noredirect=1#comment69580155_32805483)):

> Passing one argument retrieves an existing angular.Module, whereas
>   passing more than one argument creates a new angular.Module.

**Getter**

`var app = angular.module('myApp.controllers');` uses module as a getter.

It fails because the module `myApp.controllers` haven't been created yet.

**Setter**

To use it as a setter change it to

```
var app = angular.module('myApp.controllers', []); // note the []
```

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module) don't make this get/set logic very clear, but on the first line, there is the following statement: `Passing one argument retrieves an existing angular.Module, whereas passing more than one argument creates a new angular.Module`.

Comment: Thanks. I've added that.